# Is there a way in R to sum 1 column based on 2 grouped columns and a date range

Tags: r, sum

I am trying to do a sum of 1 column based on values of 3 other columns. The data is set up like this:

```
    Class|      Code|       Date|       Pay|
1   x0001       y0001       2022-01-01  10
2   x0002       y0001       2022-01-03  5
3   x0003       y0002       2022-01-15  5
4   x0003       y0002       2022-01-21  15
5   x0003       y0002       2022-02-22  10
6   x0003       y0002       2022-03-04  10
7   x0004       y0001       2022-01-04  20
8   x0004       y0001       2022-02-03  5
9   x0004       y0001       2022-03-15  30
```

I have grouped by Class and Code and I want to add up pay based on 30 business day periods for each line. So far I have this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(bizdays)
Class <- c("x0001", "x0002", "x0003", "x0003", "x0003", "x0003","x0004", "x0004", "x0004")
Code <- c("y0001", "y0001", "y0002", "y0002", "y0002", "y0002", "y0001", "y0001", "y0001")
Date <- c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-15", "2022-01-21", "2022-02-22", "2022-03-04",
      "2022-01-04", "2022-02-03", "2022-03-15")
Pay <- c(10, 5, 5, 15, 10, 10, 20, 5, 30)
df <- data.frame(Class, Code, Date, Pay)

calen <- create.calendar("Calendar", weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'), 
                     holidays <- as.Date(c("2022-01-17", "2022-02-12")), 
                     start.date = "2022-01-01", end.date = "2022-12-31", financial = FALSE)

df %>%
  group_by(Class, Code) %>%
  arrange(Class, Code, Date) %>%
  mutate(end_date1 = ifelse(weekdays(as.Date(Date)) == "Saturday" |
                          weekdays(as.Date(Date)) == "Sunday" |
                          as.Date(Date) %in% holidays, 
                        offset(Date, 30, cal = "Calendar"), 
                        offset(Date, 29, cal = "Calendar"))) %>%
  mutate(end_date = as.Date(end_date1, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  mutate(summing = ifelse(Date <= end_date, sum(Pay), 0)) %>%
  select(-end_date1)
```

I want the table print out to look like this:

```
    Class|      Code|       Date|       Pay|    end_date|   summing|    
1   x0001       y0001       2022-01-01  10      2022-02-14  10
2   x0002       y0001       2022-01-03  5       2022-02-14  5
3   x0003       y0002       2022-01-15  5       2022-02-28  30
4   x0003       y0002       2022-01-21  15      2022-03-03  35
5   x0003       y0002       2022-02-22  10      2022-04-04  20
6   x0003       y0002       2022-03-04  10      2022-04-14  10
7   x0004       y0001       2022-01-04  20      2022-02-15  25
8   x0004       y0001       2022-02-03  5       2022-03-16  35
9   x0004       y0001       2022-03-15  30      2022-04-25  30
```

The summing column is summed from the “Date” line and all the dates in the class and code group that fall within the “end_date”.

What I am getting is this:

```
    Class|      Code|       Date|       Pay|    end_date|   summing |
1   x0001       y0001       2022-01-01  10      2022-02-14  10
2   x0002       y0001       2022-01-03  5       2022-02-14  5
3   x0003       y0002       2022-01-15  5       2022-02-28  40
4   x0003       y0002       2022-01-21  15      2022-03-03  40
5   x0003       y0002       2022-02-22  10      2022-04-04  40
6   x0003       y0002       2022-03-04  10      2022-04-14  40
7   x0004       y0001       2022-01-04  20      2022-02-15  55
8   x0004       y0001       2022-02-03  5       2022-03-16  55
9   x0004       y0001       2022-03-15  30      2022-04-25  55
```

Where it sums up everything in the class and code group but ignoring the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `purrr::map2_dbl` to compute the sums:

Note: I got a different value for row 4. Perhaps a typo in your example data?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(bizdays)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  arrange(Class, Code, Date) %>%
  mutate(end_date = ifelse(
    weekdays(Date) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday", holidays),
    offset(Date, 30, cal = "Calendar"),
    offset(Date, 29, cal = "Calendar")
  )) %>%
  mutate(end_date = as.Date(end_date, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  group_by(Code, Class) %>%
  mutate(summing = map2_dbl(
    Date, end_date,
    ~ sum(Pay[Date >= .x & Date <= .y])
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 9 × 6
#>   Class Code  Date         Pay end_date   summing
#>   <chr> <chr> <date>     <dbl> <date>       <dbl>
#> 1 x0001 y0001 2022-01-01    10 2022-02-11      10
#> 2 x0002 y0001 2022-01-03     5 2022-02-14       5
#> 3 x0003 y0002 2022-01-15     5 2022-02-25      30
#> 4 x0003 y0002 2022-01-21    15 2022-03-03      25
#> 5 x0003 y0002 2022-02-22    10 2022-04-04      20
#> 6 x0003 y0002 2022-03-04    10 2022-04-14      10
#> 7 x0004 y0001 2022-01-04    20 2022-02-15      25
#> 8 x0004 y0001 2022-02-03     5 2022-03-16      35
#> 9 x0004 y0001 2022-03-15    30 2022-04-25      30
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it! Yes I think I just made a mistake trying to add quickly in my head.